# PHP Curl Translation to Google App Script Fetch URL

Tags: php, curl, google-apps-script, user-agent

I have the below working PHP code that calls an API. The API will use some of the headers and encrypt them to compare with the `Client-Signature` which is also one item in the header.

I translated to Google App Script. But unfortunately I am getting a signature error for the App Script code.

My question is, would Google App Script render the headers the same way at the PHP code shown? Because, all others issues ruled out, I am doubting that the way headers are rendered in the  HTTP request may be causing the signature issue.

If you see an other issue, please let me know. I am totally stuck here.

```
$requestId = "**";
$tokenID = "**";
$signature = "**";

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://public-api.sandbox.bunq.com/v1/user/3079/monetary-account";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "User-Agent: VBA-Web v4.1.5 (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)",
    "X-Bunq-Geolocation: 0 0 0 0 NL",
    "X-Bunq-Language: en_US",
    "X-Bunq-Region: en_US",
    "X-Bunq-Client-Request-Id: " . $requestId,
    "X-Bunq-Client-Authentication: " . $tokenID,    
    "X-Bunq-Client-Signature: " . $signature 
];
var_dump( $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump ( $server_output) ;
```

**Google App Script Code:**

```
  var requestId = "**";
  var url = "https://public-api.sandbox.bunq.com/v1/user/3079/monetary-account";
  var tokenID = "**";
  var signature = "**";
  var RequestHeader =  {
    "Cache-Control" : "no-cache",
    "Content-Type" : "application/json" ,
    "User-Agent" : "VBA-Web v4.1.5 (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)",
    "X-Bunq-Geolocation" : "0 0 0 0 NL",
    "X-Bunq-Language" : "en_US",
    "X-Bunq-Region" : "en_US",
    "X-Bunq-Client-Request-Id" : requestId,
    "X-Bunq-Client-Authentication" : tokenID,   
    "X-Bunq-Client-Signature" : signature 
  };
  var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": RequestHeader,
  muteHttpExceptions : true
 }
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response );
```

Comment: You can check which headers are set by using the `getRequest` class method and logging it (preferably to Stackdriver). You can then send that request with the `fetchAll` class method.

Comment: Putting muteHTTPExceptions  in quotes is not solving problem.

Comment: **getRequest:** {headers={X-Bunq-Geolocation=0 0 0 0 NL, X-Bunq-Client-Request-Id=**, Cache-Control=no-cache, X-Bunq-Client-Authentication=**, User-Agent=VBA-Web v4.1.5 (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web), X-Bunq-Client-Signature=**, X-Bunq-Region=en_US, X-Bunq-Language=en_US}  **PHP ** Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: VBA-Web v4.1.5 (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)
X-Bunq-Geolocation: 0 0 0 0 NL
X-Bunq-Language: en_US
X-Bunq-Region: en_US
X-Bunq-Client-Request-Id: **
X-Bunq-Client-Authentication: **
X-Bunq-Client-Signature: **

Comment: That info belongs in your question, properly formatted. @i-i quotes are only needed for defining object properties that are not valid JS identifiers

Comment: My only question is  the  headers from getRequest Show up as  X-Bunq-Geolocation=0 0 0 0 N   while verbose output of  PHP  CURL shows up as X-Bunq-Geolocation: 0 0 0 0 NL. Will both be rendered in the same way on the actual HTTP Request header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks All for your suggestions. 
Created a Web Service that  prints the headers it receives and discovered this.

Google App Script puts its own User-Agent value  irrespective of what you put at the User-Agent in fetch method. UrlFetchApp.getRequest doesn't show  what User-Agent value goes to the web service. It  only shows what you put in.

So in this case I put below value for  User-Agent in header:

> VBA-Web v4.1.5 (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)

`getRequest` shows below value for  User-Agent in the headers:

> VBA-Web v4.1.5 (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web)

When the request hits the web service below is what went in the header for User-Agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script)

Since User-Agent was used in calculating the signature, I was getting a Signature error.